# Слово "запашок"

Tags: суффиксы

Верно я понимаю, что слово ***запашок*** носит исключительно негативный оттенок?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да, Вы верно понимаете. Из словаря Кузнецова на Грамоте.ру:

ЗАПАШОК, -шка; м. Разг. **Слабый дурной запах**; душок. Мясо с запашком.

Также: **Толковый словарь Ефремовой** (современный толковый словарь русского языка)

**Запашок** м. разг. **Слабый неприятный** запах; душок.

Пример:

Напрасно они здесь развесили гирлянды этого копченого мяса. ***Запашок*** так и вьется, и кружит… А может, человеку даже и полагается пребывать в пещерной вони? [Дина Рубина. Белая голубка Кордовы (2008-2009)]

Comment: Спасибо, Sharon!

Answer (score 2):

*Владимир Кунин. Кыся (1998-2000)  

...и слабенький запашок мятной жевательной резинки, наивно призванной заглушить все остальные запахи 


Виктор Мясников. Водка (2000) 

Сквозь жирный запашок нагретых машинкой денег резко накатило Зойкиными духами 


Анатолий Найман. Любовный интерес (1998-1999)  

Но в этом случае мне и нужно было срединно общее, проверенное, устоявшееся в круге на чем-то стакнувшихся людей, как вода в неглубоком пруду, ― а тинный запашок только приятен надежностью. 


Виль Липатов. И это все о нем (1984) 

Лидия Анисимовна спокойненько удалилась, оставив в кабинете легкий запашок славных духов и глухую картавость мягкой речи: как бы зажеванные губами нотки. 


Юрий Казаков. Долгие крики (1966-1972) 

Взял сигарету, закурил, затянулся глубоко раза три, сказал только: ― Слабоваты, а так ничего, запашок приятный…


В. В. Набоков. Лолита (1967) 

Все в ней было равно непроницаемо ― мощь ее стройных ног, запачканная подошва ее белого носка, толстый свитер, которого она не сняла, несмотря на духоту в комнате, ее новый луковый запашок.*

Думаю, что "запашок" всё-таки только слабый запах.

Comment: Если слово имеет значение только "слабый запах", то обычно присутствует дополнительное определение (славный, приятный и др.). Если определения нет, то речь. скорее всего,  идет о неприятном запахе.

Comment: Без комментариев:
<br><br>
Душок - лёгкий, слабый запах. (Ефремова) <br>
https://slovar.cc/rus/efremova-slovo/1097323.html
<br><br>
Вероника лекарственная  <br>
Имеет горький вкус, слабый запах в свежем растении; при... <br>
http://edudic.ru/elr/353/
<br><br>
Рецепция запаха и его природно-культурный смысл часто дублируется у респондентов его оценкой как очень сильного или же незнакомого. Если слабый запах был назван приятным, то в более сильной концентрации он вызывает неприятие. <br>
https://cyberleninka.ru/article/n/retseptsiya-zapaha-i-ego-prirodno-kulturnyy-smysl

Comment: Мне не совсем понятен Ваш комментарий. Я всего лишь хотела сказать, что если в тексте встречается одиночное слово "запашок" (без дополнительных пояснений), то у него будет значение "неприятный запах". Это видно из приведенного мною примера. В Ваших же примерах везде есть дополнительные пояснения.

Comment: Третья ссылка - научная статья о запахах.

Comment: Посмотрите в Корпусе, там при слове "запашок" обязательно есть пояснения на неприятность запаха. И в вашем примере упоминается копчёное мясо, запах которого не обязательно неприятный.

Comment: Спасибо, конечно, за научную статью, но возьмем более простой пример. Если кто-то говорит:ну и запашок, то он какой запах имеет в виду: легкий, приятный, неприятный? Кстати, в этой теме можно проявить творческий подход. Вот интересно, с чего бы это вполне симпатичный суффикс ОК вдруг стал проявлять негативную коннотацию? Есть еще подобные примеры?

Comment: Я привел достаточно примеров, посмотрите "душок". В вашем "если" умышлено стоит "НУ И запашок", которые желательно выдать за "неприятное". Вы сами писали, что не требуется дополнительных пояснений, но оные могут быть выражены косвенно. "Запашок" - если запах еле уловим, он мал, и сказать про малую долю от чего-то, как про всю "чего-то", естественно, язык не поворачивается, отсюда и "запашок", а не "запах".

Comment: Уменьшительно-ласкательный "-ок". Пример: "ну и запашок". Уменьшительно-ласкательный "-ок" применяется 1) в том случае, когда выражается именно малая часть от нечто целого; 2) когда выражается нечто целое (сильное) в виде его же части (мягко говоря, чтоб не сказать больше).

Comment: Спасибо за Вашу точку зрения, Нижегородец!

Comment: @Нижегородиц, вы с кем  спорите - с Sharon или с составителеми словарей?

Comment: Исходя из примеров, я считаю возможным  такое замечание к словарным статьям.  В отдельных случаях значение слова "запашок" может корректироваться с помощью контекста, например: "...а так ничего, запашок приятный". Здесь только уменьшительное значение слова "запашок" связано с наличием дополнительного определения "приятный", которое отменяет словарное значение "неприятный".

Comment: @Серж, уже ни с тем и ни с другим - дал точное описание, пусть напрягутся. Запашок: употребляется 1) в том случае, когда выражается именно малая часть от нечто целого; 2) когда выражается нечто целое (сильное) в виде его же части (мягко говоря, чтоб не сказать больше). Точность трудно опровергнуть.